# arranging 2 blue balls, 2 red balls and 1 green ball

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to arrange 2 blue balls, 2 red balls and 1 green ball?

My Answer: $$\frac{5!}{2!*2!}$$

If this is incorrect then please help me understand where I am wrong.
But if this is correct then please help me with this:

"A bag holds $4$ red marbles, $5$ blue marbles, and $2$ green marbles. If $5$ marbles are selected one after another without replacement, what is the probability of drawing $2$ red marbles, $2$ blue marbles, and $1$ green marble?"

Correct Answer:
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}\left(\frac{4}{11}\right)\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)\left(\frac{5}{9}\right)\left(\frac{4}{8}\right)\left(\frac{2}{7}\right) = \frac{20}{77}$$

why does it have this?
$$\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1}$$
instead of this:
$$\frac{5!}{2!*2!}$$

for more info, you can refer to my pervious question here:
[Basic combinations logic doubt in probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3177997/basic-combinations-logic-doubt-in-probability)

Comment: The answer you have given is correct. But you know what Lucky, even if it seems like the questions are similar in nature, it will be better to ask them separately, but link these similar questions in that post. So the EDIT part from the previous question should be asked as a separate question, it needs its own attention.

Comment: Yes, I thought so as well. that's why I posted this question. but I left that edit part over there just in case the people who answered my previous question come online to see it.

Comment: True, but rather than hope that people see it, *ensure* that people see it by creating a new question. Don't worry, there's enough cyberspace for you, and your question will get more attention if it is written well. Also, learn MathJax or at least keep the tricks\tips meta page open while you type so you can get the question right first time.

Comment: ok, let me do that then but I really don't wanna pis.s off those guys who answered my last question (as they are mods.)
I just thought that they would be upset that I am asking the same question again if I didn't ask this over there itself as this is basically just a very small part of that other question.
but if you say so, I would edit this question with all the info from the other question. :)

Comment: It is not the same question, it is a clarification of a similar question. I think you can justify this.

Comment: ok. sounds good, let me edit this then. thank :)

Comment: Check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for more tips.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг:
does the question seem fine now?

Comment: This is much$^{37}$ better (or should that be $37 \times$ much?)

Comment: hahahaha, thanks. :)
well, this edit got me a downvote, no idea why. :(

Comment: Sure, I don't know as well, but I am writing an answer, so I request you to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 
$$
\color{blue}{\binom 52 \binom 32 \binom 11 = \frac{5!}{2! \times 2!} = 30} 
$$

So it seems that what you are doing is also correct. However, your thought processes when computing the answer were different, so I will just highlight that.

- What was the person who wrote the "correct answer" thinking? He was thinking : let me first decide when the blue balls were drawn, followed by when the red balls were drawn, followed by when the green ball was drawn. So what he did was this : the first $\binom 52$ represents the two *chosen* spots in which the red balls were drawn. Then, these spots are gone, so from the remaining three spots, two were chosen for the red balls, and then the one remaining spot for the green ball. This is why the answer is written in that order as well.
- What were you thinking? Probably : you assumed all the balls are different, then the number of orders in which they can appear is $5!$. Now, you remembered that two of them are blue and two of them are red, so for this you divided by $2!$ twice to account for that.

And your answers are the same, because both the ways of thinking about the problem are correct, and therefore will lead to the same answer!

Comment: thank you, this is very insightful. :)

Comment: You are welcome! Keep the guidelines for asking questions in mind, it will be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It is because they are in fact equal.$$\begin{align}\binom 5 2\binom 32\binom 11&=\dfrac{5!}{2!~3!}\dfrac{3!}{2!~1!}\dfrac{1!}{1!~0!}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{5!}{2!~2!~1!}\end{align}$$

Some just prefer presenting such expressions as binomial coefficients as it reflects the logic used to derive the expression.

I rather the multinomial form. $$\binom 5{2,2,1}$$Use whatever you find most comfortable.

Comment: oops. yes, indeed. my bad. I interpreted it wrong.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This is called **The Mississippi Formula** and yes you are correct! Basically you are getting rid of the "overcounts" by dividing by 2! 2!